# Exercise about an operator (adjoint and spectrum)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $y\in c_0$ and define the operator from $l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ as the following
$$T\bigg(\sum x_n e_n\bigg) \mapsto \sum y_n x_n e_n.$$ 
I have shown that the operator is continuous, compact and selfadjoint, but I am not so sure about its spectrum.

**My attempt:**

From definition we look for $\lambda$ such that $\lambda I - T$ is not inevitable. And I know a theorem says that for a compact operator, the spectrum is just its eigenvalues and zero.

To find its eigenvalues, let $h$ be a non zero element of $l^2$, then set 
$$\lambda h - \sum y_n h_n e_n = 0$$ 
$$\sum (\lambda - y_n)h_n e_n = 0$$
Then I can see that each $y_n$ is an eigenvalue with $e_n$ being its eigenvector.

**Questions:**

1. Is this a good way of finding the spectrum of an operator in general? We pick a non-zero $x$ in the space and solve for the equation 
   $$\lambda x - T(x) = 0$$
2. Are there any other propositions about spectrum that would be useful? Like the result about the spectrum of a compact operator.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please explain how you concluded $y_n$ is an eigenvalue from $((\lambda - y_n)h_n)=(0)$ ?

Comment: @SrinivasK take $h = e_i$, the eigenvector, then $$\lambda e_i - Te_i = \sum_n (\lambda - y_n) (e_i,e_n) e_n = (\lambda - y_i) e_i = 0,$$ then we see that $y_i$ is eigenvalue for each eivenvector $e_i$.

Comment: That's fine. I got confused because you had mentioned "...To find its eigenvalues, let $h$ be **a non zero element** of $l^2$, then set...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operator is already diagonalized, and it is clear that $Te_{n}=y_{n}e_{n}$ for $n \ge 1$. So $\{ y_{n}\}$ are eigenvalues. The eigenvectors of a selfadjoint operator are orthogonal for different eigenvalues. Nothing except the $0$ vector is orthogonal to $e_{n}$ for all $n$. So there can't be any other eigenvalues. Now you know that the spectrum of $T$ is $\{ y_{n} \}\cup \{0\}$ because $T$ is compact.